# Auto Fill Form - From Pressed Link

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this website: [website link](http://www.45design.com/clients/party/invitations/bt-element/)

When the user clicks on one of the items in the gallery, I want the image to open (in a lightbox ?). Here I want to have a link to a prefilled contact form with the item in question.

someone provided me this code to get start but it only auto fills the form. It doesn't forward to the contact form and auto fill it in.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="packageDescription">
    <input type="text" id="packagePrice">
</form>

<script>

    function autoFill(packageDescription, packagePrice) {

        document.getElementById('packageDescription').value = packageDescription;
        document.getElementById('packagePrice').value = packagePrice;

    }

</script>

<a href="#" onClick="autoFill('Premium Package', 150); return false;">Premium Package</a><br>
<a href="#" onClick="autoFill('Platinum Package', 350); return false;">Platinum Package</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: So the form is on a different page than where the links are?

Comment: this code works fine.But where is your contact form? on the same page or other page?

Comment: Yes the form is on a separate page but as you can see from the website link there is multiple products. Also I have not created the contact form yet, I was trying to get this worked out first.

Answer (score -1):

This code given to you will only work if the **link** itself and **contact form** found in the same page

Comment: Yeah I found that out, it's why I was asking for help on this and thanks for your fast reply to my request.